# Finding Whether Tab Keypress was In Last Field of Cloned Rows

Tags: jquery

I have a row of divs that will add a new row when the user exits the last field. The code functions fine, and my function detects when I have exited the last field in a row, which calls the function to clone a new row.. My only problem is I cannot figure out how to detect when the last row field exited is the last field in the last row. Otherwise, it will detect the last field in any row, which is not the desired outcome. A new row should only be cloned when the last field in the last row is excited.

I originally tried deleting the LastCL class, and re-establishing it in the last row, but could not figure out how to do that, and there's probably a more intelligent way to do this without messing with the AddNewRow function

So, I have rows that look like this, each holding an input. The last field in a row is a select box. each field has an id:

```
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div class="LastCL"></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div class="LastCL"></div>
       <div></div><div></div><div></div><div class="LastCL"></div>
   </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.LastCL').keydown(function(e)
{
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 9)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Need to detect here whether the exited field is the last field in the last row, or perhaps there is another way.
        AddNewRow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add a snippit with relevant code that covers the base of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('.LastCL').keydown(function(e)
{
    var LastID = $(".form-group select").last().attr('id');
    var ThisID = $(this).find("select").attr('id');
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code === 9 && ThisID == LastID)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        AddNewRow();
    }
});
```

Comment: My impression of StackOverflow is that it is here to help programmers be better programmers. Downvoting with no relevant explanation simply comes off as arrogance, not at all conducive to being helpful. The above code works fine and is working on a site that gets thousands of hits per hour. If there is a better way of doing it, explain. Downvoting working code is not helpful to anyone unless you have a better solution.